# Why is the first element in the array being assigned a value of 0.0? NOTE: Not asking about INDEX, talking about value

Tags: java

This is a high school assignment. In my first for() loop, I build an array based on user input. However, the first value of the array is skipped and set to 0.0

I have traced the code through and through, to no avail.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How long do you want the array?");
        int length = scan.nextInt();

        if(Math.abs(length) != length)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid length!");
        }
        else
        {
            double[] array = new double[length];
            for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            }

            double[] finalarray = new double[array.length];
            int finalarraycount = 1;
            double flag = -1;
            for(int x = 0; x<(array.length -1); x++)
            {
                if(array[x] > flag)
                {
                    finalarray[finalarraycount] = array[x];
                    flag = array[x];
                    finalarraycount++;

                }
            }
            System.out.print("Your array is {");
            for(int y = 0; y<finalarray.length; y++)
            {
                System.out.print(finalarray[y]);
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.println("}");


        }


    }

}
```

I would like to input a specified number of values determined by variable length into an array, and then print the array in order from smallest to largest. Instead it skips index[0], and sets it to 0.0.

Comment: As you are only doing a single pass through your array, sorting will not be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

This is just standard compiler behaviour. `finalarray[0]` is not set to anything by your second for loop. Thus, Java initialises it to 0.0, as explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Answer (score 0):

`finalarraycount` should be initialized to `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`int finalarraycount = 1;`

`finalarray[finalarraycount] = array[x];`

This is why. You initialize it as 1 but the first index in the array is 0. If this was 0, it would affect the first index in the array.